# Is there a quicker proof to show that $2^{10^k} \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$ for all positive integers $k$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I noticed this pattern while playing with digit sums and noticed that the recursive digit sums (until you arrive at a single digit number) of numbers like, $2^{10}$, $2^{100}$, $2^{1000}$ and so on is always $7$. So, I decided to find out if it is true that for all positive integers $k$,

$$ 2^{10^k} \equiv 7 \pmod{9} $$

My proof is as follows:

---

**Lemma 1.** *$\, 10^k \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$ for all integers $k \geq 1$*

*Proof.* For all integers $k \geq 1$, the number $10^k + 2$ must be divisible by $6$ since it is even (implying divisibility by $2$), and its digit sum is $3$ (implying divisibility by $3$). Therefore, you can show that
\begin{align*}
10^k + 2 &\equiv 0 \pmod{6} \\
10^k &\equiv 4 \pmod{6} \,\, \text{    for all integers  } k \geq 1
\end{align*}

**Lemma 2.** *$\, 2^{4 + 6k} \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$, for all integers $k \geq 0$*

*Proof.* If $a \equiv c \pmod{n}$ and $b \equiv d \pmod{n}$, then $a\,b \equiv c\,d \pmod{n}$.
And, by extension, $a\,b^k \equiv c\,d^k \pmod{n}$ (for integers $k \geq 0$). Therefore, with
\begin{align*}
2^4 \equiv 16 \equiv 7 \pmod{9}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
2^6 \equiv 64 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}
\end{align*}
we can show that,
\begin{align*}
2^{4 + 6k} \equiv 7 \cdot 1^k \equiv 7 \pmod{9} \,\, \text{    for all integers  } k \geq 0
\end{align*}

**Theorem.** *$\, 2^{10^k} \equiv 7 \pmod{9} $ for all integers $k \geq 1$*

Lemma 1 implies that for all integers $k \geq 1$, $10^k = 4 + 6n$ where $n$ is some positive integer. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
2^{10^k} &= 2^{4 + 6n} \\
2^{10^k} \!\!\!\! \mod a &= 2^{4 + 6n} \!\!\!\! \mod a
\end{align*}
for any positive integer $a$. Using this result along with Lemma 2, 
\begin{align*}
2^{10^k} \equiv 7 \pmod{9} \,\, \text{    for all integers  } k \geq 1
\end{align*}
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

---

I think the proof is correct, but I am not a fan of it. Mainly because, I think proving Lemma 2 is a much too long a way to prove this theorem - since it proves a generalization of the theorem first. Also, I discovered that lemma numerically, which feels a bit like cheating.

Either way, is there a quicker, more elegant proof which does not:

1. Use Lemma 2, or prove some generalization of the theorem first.
2. Uses Euler's Theorem. I feel that using Euler's Theorem is using a needlessly complicated theorem to prove something as simple as this.

I am sure some of the people here can come up with single line proofs. I am curious to see if there's such a proof.

Comment: euler's theorem is one of the basic tools when working with exponents

Comment: Do you mean is there a shorter proof ?

Comment: Well...$2^{10}\equiv 7\pmod 9$ and $7^{10}\equiv 7\pmod 9$.  Then go by induction.

Comment: "I feel using Euler's theorem is using a needlessly complicated theorem to prove something as simple as this"  well, that is just *silly*!  The *entire* reason to have complicated theorems is because they are versitile and so you won't *have* to prove simple propositions like this over and over again.  "Proof: it follows directly from Euler's theorem".  That is a six word proof and it is enough!  It's ... silly... to give a six paragraph 2 lemma prove and then complain a six *word* proof is too complicated.  It's not like we have prove Euler th. Every time we use it.

Comment: @fleablood Moise once referred to it as something like using a tractor where a shovel would do. It's very natural to wonder if there is a more elementary solution. There is nothing inherently wrong with finding more than one way to solve a problem. How many proofs of quadratic reciprocity exists?

Comment: Ah, well, no we are discussing *why* we are proving anything at all.  After all, if we just want to know if something is true, having someone smarter than us say "It is; trust me" is usually enough.  I guess my feeling is that Euler's theorem was complicated to *prove* it is simple to *use*.  Analogy: "What does 'diffident' mean?" "I don't know; look in the dictionary".  "Whoa! The dictionary took 15 years to edit and involved researching 200,000 words! Don't you think that's a lot of *work* when I just want to know *one* measly word?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Induction? Base case when $k=1$ is clear, for inductive step we have: $2^{10^k}=(2^{10^{k-1}})^{10}\equiv 7^{10}\equiv 7\bmod 9$

Comment: How did you get $7^{10} \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$ without evaluating in a computer?

Comment: we can go $7^{10}\equiv (-2)^{10}\equiv 2^{10}$. And you already know $2^{10}\equiv 9$. So we don't need no extra stuff

Comment: @CarryonSmiling You mean $2^{10}\equiv 7$. It simply follows from $1+0+2+4\equiv 7\pmod{9}$.

Answer (score 3):

Don't fear Euler's theorem.  You have it.  Use it.  It's not like it costs a lot of gas money or you have to pay tolls.

$2^6 \equiv 1 \mod 9$ so $2^{10^k} \equiv 2^{(10^k \mod 6 = 4^k \mod 6)} \mod 9$.

One little observation.  If $4^n \equiv 4 \mod 6$ then $4^{n+1} \equiv 16 \equiv 4 \mod 6$ so inductively $4^n \equiv 4 \mod 6$ for all $n$.

So $2^{10^k} \equiv 2^{4^k} \equiv 2^4 =16 \equiv 7 \mod 9$.